# invalid syntax error python, runs on codeacademy but doesn't in pycharm

Tags: python, syntax

```
str1 = "mike"
str2 = "demon"

print "hi %s, i like %s" % (str1, str2)
```

error is

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Do you use Python-3.x in PyCharm? Because then you have to write `print("hi %s, i like %s" % (str1, str2))`. In Python-3.x, `print` is no longer a keyword, but a function.

Comment: Try to include with brackets. i.e. print("hi %s, i like %s" % (str1, str2))

Comment: Voting to close because of typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [What’s New In Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)

> The `print` statement has been replaced with a `print()` function.

You should use parentheses:

```
str1 = "mike"
str2 = "demon"

print("hi %s, i like %s" % (str1, str2))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using python 3 so it won't work there since print is a function, not a key word. You can see an example here https://repl.it/Kw7R/1